# GCC Cannot Optimize Away Redundant Coordinate Transformation Function Calls Even If Marked as "Pure" in Custom ND-Array Classes

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

#### Background and Motivation

I'm working on optimizing a numerical solver for simulating Maxwell's equations using the finite difference method.

Note that the actual problem has little to do with physics, numerical simulations, or even the related optimization techniques. It's in fact only a tiny problem encountered during the implementation of a custom array wrapper. But for completeness, minimum details are described here.

In the simulation, physical space is discretized as a 3D grid `(i, j, k)`, which can be represented as a 3D array. Within the grid, the value of each cell is a 3-vector `(x, y, z)`, representing the numerical value of the electromagnetic field or material properties on the X, Y, or Z axis. Thus, the simulation box can be represented as a 4D array `(i, j, k, n)`, where `n = 0, 1, 2` (alternatively, it's simply a 3D array with 3-vectors).

During each timestep, four such 4D arrays are involved in the calculating of the new electric field. They're:

- `volt`, `curr` - electric and magnetic fields.
- `vv`, `vi` - material properties

The Kokkos parallel programming library is used for writing GPU-shader style data parallel code on the CPU, its native N-D array implementation `Kokkos::View` is also used.

#### Custom Array Classes

To enable further optimizations, the first thing I needed to do is 3D domain decomposition. Instead of iterating every cell in the 3D array according to the standard C order `[i][j][k]`, the array is iterated on the basic unit of 3D tiles, such as a 20x20x20 tile. This is known as loop tiling or loop blocking. As a result, the underlying layout of the arrays must also be stored in a matching order (otherwise, the performance degradation can be significant, especially because the stride-1 `K` dimension is no longer accessed contiguously).

To achieve this, I've implemented a custom array wrapper with overloaded `()` operator on top of `Kokkos::View`. This way, the wrapper can transparently translate the global coordinate of a cell `(gi, gj, gk)` to its tile coordinates `(ti, tj, tk)`. It also allows one to experiment with many different array layouts without changing code.

First, a `Grid` class is defined. This class is only used to represent the abstract simulation grid:

```
    Grid(
            std::array<uint32_t, 3> grid_size,
            std::array<uint32_t, 3> tile_size
    ) :
```

It knows the dimensions of the grid and it also knows how to perform coordinate transformations, exposed using the member function:

```
    __attribute__((always_inline, pure))
    std::array<uint32_t, 4> global_coords_to_tile(
            const uint32_t gi,
            const uint32_t gj,
            const uint32_t gk
    ) const
```

Next, the `ArrayIJKN` class is implemented. It uses the dimensions provided by `Grid` to create a simulation box in memory, and it also uses the provided coordinate transformation functions.

```
    ArrayIJKN(
        const std::string& name,
        const Grid& grid
    ) :
        m_grid(&grid)
    {
        uint32_t tile_num = grid.tile_num[DIM_I] * grid.tile_num[DIM_J] * grid.tile_num[DIM_K];

        // Yes, it's 5-level of indirection and can be considered a bad style
        // elsewhere, but this Kokkos::View template is officially designed to be
        // used this way. It templated for compile-time support of N-D arrays up
        // to 8 dimensions. 
        // 
        // The first dimension select a tile, the next 3 dimensions select a
        // cell within the 3D tile, the final dimension select the polarization
        // (X, Y, Z).
        m_ijk = new Kokkos::View<T****[n_num]>(
            Kokkos::ViewAllocateWithoutInitializing(name),
            tile_num,
            grid.tile_size[DIM_I], grid.tile_size[DIM_J], grid.tile_size[DIM_K],
            n_num
        );
    }
```

This class is the actual wrapper class. It accepts the previously created `grid` object to create an underlying 5D array `(tile_id, ti, tj, tk, n)`. A value can be accessed under this "tile coordinate system". But to allow experimenting with different layouts transparently, it also allows one to access the array using the standard 4D global coordinate system `(gi, gj, gk, n)` by overloading the `operator ()`. Within this member function, it uses `grid.global_coords_to_tile()` provided by `Grid` class to transform the coordinates from the global system to the tile system.

This is implemented as follows:

```
    __attribute__((always_inline, pure))
    T& operator() (
            const uint32_t gi,
            const uint32_t gj,
            const uint32_t gk,
            const uint32_t n
    ) const
    {
            auto coords = (*m_grid).global_coords_to_tile(gi, gj, gk);
            return (*m_ijk)(coords[TILE_ID], coords[TILE_I], coords[TILE_J], coords[TILE_K], n);
    }
```

#### Problem

Finally, the following mock-up compute kernel is executed (the physical update equations are changed solely for testing array accesses). In a release build, it's automatic parallelized and inlined into the tiled loop by Kokkos.

As a reference, here's a kernel that explicitly transforms the coordinates from the global system to the tile system before accessing all arrays:

```
void UpdateVoltagesKernel(
    Grid grid,
    ArrayIJKN<float> volt,
    ArrayIJKN<float> curr,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vv,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vi,
    uint32_t gi, uint32_t gj, uint32_t gk
)
{
    auto tile_coords = grid.global_coords_to_tile(gi, gj, gk);
    uint32_t tile_id = tile_coords[TILE_ID];
    uint32_t si = tile_coords[TILE_I];
    uint32_t sj = tile_coords[TILE_J];
    uint32_t sk = tile_coords[TILE_K];

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float volt0 = volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float volt1 = volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float volt2 = volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vv0 = vv(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float vv1 = vv(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float vv2 = vv(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vi0 = vi(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float vi1 = vi(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float vi2 = vi(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float curr0 = curr(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float curr1 = curr(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float curr2 = curr(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    //for x polarization
    volt0 *= vv0;
    volt0 += vi0 * curr0;

    //for y polarization
    volt1 *= vv1;
    volt1 += vi1 * curr1;

    //for z polarization
    volt2 *= vv2;
    volt2 += vi2 * curr2;

    // 3 FP32 stores
    volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0) = volt0;
    volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1) = volt1;
    volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2) = volt2;
}
```

This kernel has good performance. Benchmarks showed that on a dual-socket Intel Xeon E5-2680 v4 (I already properly handled NUMA first touch), when the kernel is automatically parallelized across all cores using `Kokkos::parallel_for()`, it reaches a speed of 80 GB/s with GCC 12.3.1 with `-O3 -march=native`. With LLVM/clang 18.0, the speed is even greater, at over 100 GB/s. Apparently, it's due to the fact that LLVM inlines more aggressively, as I can replicate the same performance with GCC using `__attribute__((always_inline))`. 100+ GB/s is very close to my CPU's peak memory bandwidth obtained via the STREAM-like benchmark such as `triad` or `daxpy`, thus the kernel exhibits great performance.

Next, the equivalent kernel without explicit coordinate transformation is also tested:

```
#define ASSUME(cond)                    \
    do {                                \
        if (!(cond))                    \
            __builtin_unreachable();    \
    } while (0)


void UpdateVoltagesKernel(
    ArrayIJKN<float> volt,
    ArrayIJKN<float> curr,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vv,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vi,
    uint32_t i, uint32_t j, uint32_t k
)
{
    //ASSUME(volt.m_grid == curr.m_grid);
    //ASSUME(volt.m_grid == vv.m_grid);
    //ASSUME(volt.m_grid == vi.m_grid);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float volt0 = volt(i, j, k, 0);
    float volt1 = volt(i, j, k, 1);
    float volt2 = volt(i, j, k, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vv0 = vv(i, j, k, 0);
    float vv1 = vv(i, j, k, 1);
    float vv2 = vv(i, j, k, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vi0 = vi(i, j, k, 0);
    float vi1 = vi(i, j, k, 1);
    float vi2 = vi(i, j, k, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float curr0 = curr(i, j, k, 0);
    float curr1 = curr(i, j, k, 1);
    float curr2 = curr(i, j, k, 2);

    //for x polarization
    volt0 *= vv0;
    volt0 += vi0 * curr0;

    //for y polarization
    volt1 *= vv1;
    volt1 += vi1 * curr1;

    //for z polarization
    volt2 *= vv2;
    volt2 += vi2 * curr2;

    // 3 FP32 stores
    volt(i, j, k, 0) = volt0;
    volt(i, j, k, 1) = volt1;
    volt(i, j, k, 2) = volt2;
}
```

But testing showed that this kernel has poor performance, running at a speed of only 40 GB/s - only half as fast as the first kernel (80 GB/s) in GCC. By examining the assembly ounput, one immediately notices that the compiler failed to optimize the redundant implicit global coordinate function calls to `Grid::global_coords_to_tile`, as a result, many extra multiplications and divisions are generated.

The assembly output of the explicit kernel has only 100 lines of code and just 3 divisions:

```
_Z20UpdateVoltagesKernel4Grid9ArrayIJKNIfLj3EES1_S1_S1_jjj:
.LFB8832:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 14, -16
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    movq    %rsi, %r8
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 12, -24
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 6, -32
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    .cfi_offset 3, -40
    movl    96(%rsp), %eax
    movq    8(%r8), %rbx
    movq    88(%rsp), %r11
    movq    8(%r9), %r12
    divl    52(%rsp)
    movq    32(%r11), %r14
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    104(%rsp), %eax
    imull   68(%rsp), %esi
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    56(%rsp)
    movl    %eax, %ebp
    movl    112(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %r10d
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    addl    %ebp, %esi
    imull   72(%rsp), %esi
    movq    32(%r8), %rbp
    divl    60(%rsp)
    addl    %esi, %eax
    movl    24(%r8), %esi
    movl    %eax, %eax
    imull   %ecx, %esi
    imulq   %rax, %rbp
    imulq   %rax, %r14
    addl    %r10d, %esi
    imull   28(%r8), %esi
    movq    32(%r9), %r8
    imulq   %rax, %r8
    addl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %esi, %esi
    leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rsi
    addq    %rbp, %rsi
    salq    $2, %rsi
    leaq    (%rbx,%rsi), %rbp
    leaq    8(%rbx,%rsi), %rbx
    movl    24(%r9), %esi
    imull   %ecx, %esi
    addl    %r10d, %esi
    imull   28(%r9), %esi
    movq    8(%r11), %r9
    addl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %esi, %esi
    leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rsi
    addq    %r8, %rsi
    movl    24(%r11), %r8d
    imull   %ecx, %r8d
    imull   24(%rdi), %ecx
    addl    %r10d, %r8d
    imull   28(%r11), %r8d
    movq    8(%rdi), %r11
    addl    %r10d, %ecx
    imull   28(%rdi), %ecx
    addl    %edx, %r8d
    movl    %r8d, %r8d
    leaq    (%r8,%r8,2), %r8
    addq    %r14, %r8
    addl    %ecx, %edx
    vmovss  8(%r9,%r8,4), %xmm0
    imulq   32(%rdi), %rax
    movl    %edx, %edx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdx,2), %rdx
    vmovq   (%r9,%r8,4), %xmm4
    vmovq   0(%rbp), %xmm1
    vmovq   (%r12,%rsi,4), %xmm3
    vmovss  (%rbx), %xmm5
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    vmovq   (%r11,%rax,4), %xmm2
    vmulss  8(%r11,%rax,4), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vfmadd231ss 8(%r12,%rsi,4), %xmm5, %xmm0
    vmulps  %xmm4, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vfmadd132ps %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vmovlps %xmm1, 0(%rbp)
    vmovss  %xmm0, (%rbx)
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

But the assembly output of the implicit kernel has 150 lines of code with 12 divisions. These divisions have massively reduced CPU's throughput.

```
_Z20UpdateVoltagesKernel9ArrayIJKNIfLj3EES0_S0_S0_jjj:
.LFB8832:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r15
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 15, -16
    pushq   %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 14, -24
    pushq   %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 13, -32
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    .cfi_offset 12, -40
    movq    %rsi, %r12
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    .cfi_offset 6, -48
    movq    %r9, %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 56
    .cfi_offset 3, -56
    movl    72(%rsp), %eax
    movq    %rcx, %rbx
    movq    8(%r12), %r15
    movq    56(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    64(%rsp), %r13
    divl    12(%rdi)
    movl    %eax, %r11d
    movl    80(%rsp), %eax
    imull   28(%rdi), %r11d
    movl    %edx, %r10d
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    imull   24(%r12), %r10d
    divl    16(%rdi)
    movl    %eax, %r14d
    movl    88(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %r9d
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    addl    %r14d, %r11d
    imull   32(%rdi), %r11d
    addl    %r9d, %r10d
    divl    20(%rdi)
    imull   28(%r12), %r10d
    addl    %r11d, %eax
    addl    %r10d, %edx
    movl    %eax, %eax
    imulq   32(%r12), %rax
    movl    %edx, %edx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdx,2), %rdx
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    salq    $2, %rax
    leaq    (%r15,%rax), %r11
    leaq    8(%r15,%rax), %r10
    movl    72(%rsp), %eax
    vmovq   (%r11), %xmm1
    divl    12(%r8)
    movl    %eax, %r9d
    movl    80(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %edi
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    16(%r8)
    movl    %eax, %r15d
    movl    88(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %r14d
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    20(%r8)
    movq    8(%rbp), %r12
    imull   28(%r8), %r9d
    imull   24(%rbp), %edi
    addl    %r15d, %r9d
    imull   32(%r8), %r9d
    movq    8(%r13), %r15
    addl    %r14d, %edi
    imull   28(%rbp), %edi
    addl    %eax, %r9d
    leal    (%rdi,%rdx), %eax
    movl    %r9d, %r9d
    imulq   32(%rbp), %r9
    leaq    (%rax,%rax,2), %rax
    addq    %rax, %r9
    movl    72(%rsp), %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    vmovq   (%r12,%r9,4), %xmm3
    divl    12(%rcx)
    movl    %eax, %r8d
    movl    80(%rsp), %eax
    imull   28(%rcx), %r8d
    movl    %edx, %edi
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    imull   24(%r13), %edi
    divl    16(%rcx)
    movl    %eax, %r14d
    movl    88(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %ebp
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    addl    %r14d, %r8d
    imull   32(%rcx), %r8d
    addl    %ebp, %edi
    divl    20(%rcx)
    imull   28(%r13), %edi
    addl    %r8d, %eax
    addl    %edi, %edx
    movl    %eax, %eax
    imulq   32(%r13), %rax
    movl    %edx, %edx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdx,2), %rdx
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    vmovq   (%r15,%rax,4), %xmm4
    vmovss  8(%r15,%rax,4), %xmm0
    movl    72(%rsp), %eax
    divl    12(%rsi)
    movl    %eax, %edi
    movl    80(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    16(%rsi)
    movl    %eax, %r13d
    movl    88(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %r8d
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    divl    20(%rsi)
    movq    8(%rbx), %rbp
    vmovss  (%r10), %xmm5
    imull   28(%rsi), %edi
    imull   24(%rbx), %ecx
    addl    %r13d, %edi
    imull   32(%rsi), %edi
    addl    %r8d, %ecx
    imull   28(%rbx), %ecx
    addl    %edi, %eax
    addl    %ecx, %edx
    movl    %eax, %eax
    imulq   32(%rbx), %rax
    movl    %edx, %edx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdx,2), %rdx
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    vmovq   0(%rbp,%rax,4), %xmm2
    vmulss  8(%rbp,%rax,4), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vfmadd231ss 8(%r12,%r9,4), %xmm5, %xmm0
    vmulps  %xmm4, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vfmadd132ps %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vmovlps %xmm1, (%r11)
    vmovss  %xmm0, (%r10)
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    popq    %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    popq    %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r15
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

It's obvious that the compiler has failed to remove duplicate calls to `Grid::global_coords_to_tile`. Thus, the coordinate transformations are repeated many timen than what's strictly necessary.

Indeed, when the following code is added to the implicit kernel to tell the compiler that `volt.m_grid`, `curr.m_grid`, `vv.m_grid`, and `vi.m_grid` are the same things, LLVM/clang was able to accept this hint and generate code as fast as the explicit kernel:

```
#define ASSUME(cond)                    \
    do {                                \
        if (!(cond))                    \
            __builtin_unreachable();    \
    } while (0)

    ASSUME(volt.m_grid == curr.m_grid);
    ASSUME(volt.m_grid == vv.m_grid);
    ASSUME(volt.m_grid == vi.m_grid);
```

With these assumptions added to the implicit kernel, on LLVM/clang, the speed is over 100 GB/s, as fast as the explicit kernel. Unfortunately, when compiled with GCC 12, it's unable to understand these hints - it's worth noting that it's still the case even after `ArrayIJKN::operator()` and `Grid::global_coords_to_tile` are marked as `__attribute__((always_inline, pure))`. Pure functions are supposed to allow the elimination of repeated calls, but GCC is still unable to do that in my case.

Since GCC 13, the support for `assume` has finally been added officially in GCC, but such a new version of GCC is unavailable in many systems.

### Question

Is there an similar but more efficient way to implement the implicit array accessing syntax `array(gi, gj, gk, n)` to hide the underlying coordinate transformation details?

Is there a workaround to allow GCC to optimize repeated calls away no they no longer causes performance problems? Failing that, is there an alternative programming style that implements the same syntatic suger, but without this performance penality?

### Appendix: Full Source Code

#### kernel.hpp

```
enum {
    DIM_I = 0,
    DIM_J = 1,
    DIM_K = 2
};

enum {
    TILE_ID = 0,
    TILE_I = 1,
    TILE_J = 2,
    TILE_K = 3
};

struct Grid
{
    Grid(
        std::array<uint32_t, 3> grid_size,
        std::array<uint32_t, 3> tile_size
    ) :
        grid_size(grid_size),
        tile_size(tile_size),
        tile_num{
            grid_size[DIM_I] / tile_size[DIM_I],
                        grid_size[DIM_J] / tile_size[DIM_J],
                        grid_size[DIM_K] / tile_size[DIM_K]
        }
    {
    }

    __attribute__((always_inline, pure))
    std::array<uint32_t, 4> global_coords_to_tile(
        const uint32_t gi,
        const uint32_t gj,
        const uint32_t gk
    ) const
    {
        uint32_t tile_id_i = gi / tile_size[DIM_I];
        uint32_t tile_id_j = gj / tile_size[DIM_J];
        uint32_t tile_id_k = gk / tile_size[DIM_K];
        uint32_t tile_id = tile_id_i * tile_num[DIM_J] * tile_num[DIM_K] + tile_id_j * tile_num[DIM_K] + tile_id_k;

        uint32_t ti = gi % tile_size[DIM_I];
        uint32_t tj = gj % tile_size[DIM_J];
        uint32_t tk = gk % tile_size[DIM_K];

        return {tile_id, ti, tj, tk};
    }

    const std::array<uint32_t, 3> grid_size;
    const std::array<uint32_t, 3> tile_size;
    const std::array<uint32_t, 3> tile_num;
};

template <typename T, uint32_t n_num=3>
struct ArrayIJKN
{
    ArrayIJKN(
        const std::string& name,
        const Grid& grid
    ) :
        m_grid(&grid)
    {
        uint32_t tile_num = grid.tile_num[DIM_I] * grid.tile_num[DIM_J] * grid.tile_num[DIM_K];

        m_ijk = new Kokkos::View<T****[n_num]>(
            Kokkos::ViewAllocateWithoutInitializing(name),
            tile_num,
            grid.tile_size[DIM_I], grid.tile_size[DIM_J], grid.tile_size[DIM_K], n_num
        );
    }

    T& operator() (
        const uint32_t tile_id,
        const uint32_t ti,
        const uint32_t tj,
        const uint32_t tk,
        const uint32_t n
    ) const
    {
        return (*m_ijk)(tile_id, ti, tj, tk, n);
    }

    __attribute__((always_inline, pure))
    T& operator() (
        const uint32_t gi,
        const uint32_t gj,
        const uint32_t gk,
        const uint32_t n
    ) const
    {
        auto coords = (*m_grid).global_coords_to_tile(gi, gj, gk);
        return (*m_ijk)(coords[TILE_ID], coords[TILE_I], coords[TILE_J], coords[TILE_K], n);
    }

    const Grid* __restrict__ m_grid;
    Kokkos::View<T****[n_num]>* __restrict__ m_ijk;
};
```

#### explicit.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <Kokkos_Core.hpp>

#include "kernel.hpp"

void UpdateVoltagesKernel(
    Grid grid,
    ArrayIJKN<float> volt,
    ArrayIJKN<float> curr,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vv,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vi,
    uint32_t gi, uint32_t gj, uint32_t gk
)
{
    auto tile_coords = grid.global_coords_to_tile(gi, gj, gk);
    uint32_t tile_id = tile_coords[TILE_ID];
    uint32_t si = tile_coords[TILE_I];
    uint32_t sj = tile_coords[TILE_J];
    uint32_t sk = tile_coords[TILE_K];

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float volt0 = volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float volt1 = volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float volt2 = volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vv0 = vv(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float vv1 = vv(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float vv2 = vv(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vi0 = vi(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float vi1 = vi(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float vi2 = vi(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float curr0 = curr(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0);
    float curr1 = curr(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1);
    float curr2 = curr(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2);

    //for x polarization
    volt0 *= vv0;
    volt0 += vi0 * curr0;

    //for y polarization
    volt1 *= vv1;
    volt1 += vi1 * curr1;

    //for z polarization
    volt2 *= vv2;
    volt2 += vi2 * curr2;

    // 3 FP32 stores
    volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 0) = volt0;
    volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 1) = volt1;
    volt(tile_id, si, sj, sk, 2) = volt2;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::array<uint32_t, 3> numLines = {
        200, 200, 200
    };
    std::array<uint32_t, 3> dimTiles = {
        20, 20, 20
    };

    const int timesteps = 100;

    Kokkos::initialize(argc, argv);

    auto grid = Grid(numLines, dimTiles);

    auto volt = ArrayIJKN<float>("volt", grid);
    auto curr = ArrayIJKN<float>("curr", grid);

    auto vv = ArrayIJKN<float>("vv", grid);
    auto vi = ArrayIJKN<float>("vi", grid);
    auto ii = ArrayIJKN<float>("ii", grid);
    auto iv = ArrayIJKN<float>("iv", grid);

    Kokkos::parallel_for("First Touch",
        Kokkos::MDRangePolicy<Kokkos::Rank<3>> (
            {0, 0, 0},
            {numLines[0], numLines[1], numLines[2]},
            {dimTiles[0], dimTiles[1], dimTiles[2]}
        ),
        [=](
            const uint32_t i,
            const uint32_t j,
            const uint32_t k
        ) {
            for (uint32_t n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                volt(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                curr(i, j, k, n) = 0;

                vv(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                vi(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                iv(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                ii(i, j, k, n) = 0;
            }
        }
    );
    Kokkos::fence();

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock().now();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < timesteps; i++) {
        Kokkos::parallel_for("UpdateVoltages",
            Kokkos::MDRangePolicy<Kokkos::Rank<3>> (
                {0, 0, 0},
                {numLines[0], numLines[1], numLines[2]},
                {dimTiles[0], dimTiles[1], dimTiles[2]}
            ),
            [=](
                const uint32_t gi,
                const uint32_t gj,
                const uint32_t gk
            ) {
                UpdateVoltagesKernel(grid, volt, curr, vv, vi, gi, gj, gk);
            }
        );

        Kokkos::fence();
    }

    Kokkos::fence();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock().now();
    double dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() / 1e6;

    size_t bytes_per_iteration = numLines[0] * numLines[1] * numLines[2] * 3 * sizeof(float);
    bytes_per_iteration *= 5;  /* volt r+w, curr, vv, vi arrays */
    fprintf(stderr, "traffic: %.1f GB/s\n", (double) bytes_per_iteration * timesteps / 1000 / 1000 / 1000);
    fprintf(stderr, "speed: %.1f GB/s\n",
        (double) bytes_per_iteration * timesteps / dt / 1000 / 1000 / 1000
    );

    Kokkos::finalize();
}
```

#### implicit.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <Kokkos_Core.hpp>

#include "kernel.hpp"

#define ASSUME(cond)                    \
    do {                                \
        if (!(cond))                    \
            __builtin_unreachable();    \
    } while (0)


void UpdateVoltagesKernel(
    ArrayIJKN<float> volt,
    ArrayIJKN<float> curr,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vv,
    ArrayIJKN<float> vi,
    uint32_t i, uint32_t j, uint32_t k
)
{
    ASSUME(volt.m_grid == curr.m_grid);
    ASSUME(volt.m_grid == vv.m_grid);
    ASSUME(volt.m_grid == vi.m_grid);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float volt0 = volt(i, j, k, 0);
    float volt1 = volt(i, j, k, 1);
    float volt2 = volt(i, j, k, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vv0 = vv(i, j, k, 0);
    float vv1 = vv(i, j, k, 1);
    float vv2 = vv(i, j, k, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float vi0 = vi(i, j, k, 0);
    float vi1 = vi(i, j, k, 1);
    float vi2 = vi(i, j, k, 2);

    // 3 FP32 loads
    float curr0 = curr(i, j, k, 0);
    float curr1 = curr(i, j, k, 1);
    float curr2 = curr(i, j, k, 2);

    //for x polarization
    volt0 *= vv0;
    volt0 += vi0 * curr0;

    //for y polarization
    volt1 *= vv1;
    volt1 += vi1 * curr1;

    //for z polarization
    volt2 *= vv2;
    volt2 += vi2 * curr2;

    // 3 FP32 stores
    volt(i, j, k, 0) = volt0;
    volt(i, j, k, 1) = volt1;
    volt(i, j, k, 2) = volt2;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::array<uint32_t, 3> numLines = {
        200, 200, 200
    };
    std::array<uint32_t, 3> dimTiles = {
        20, 20, 20
    };

    const int timesteps = 100;

    Kokkos::initialize(argc, argv);

    auto grid = Grid(numLines, dimTiles);

    auto volt = ArrayIJKN<float>("volt", grid);
    auto curr = ArrayIJKN<float>("curr", grid);

    auto vv = ArrayIJKN<float>("vv", grid);
    auto vi = ArrayIJKN<float>("vi", grid);
    auto ii = ArrayIJKN<float>("ii", grid);
    auto iv = ArrayIJKN<float>("iv", grid);

    Kokkos::parallel_for("First Touch",
        Kokkos::MDRangePolicy<Kokkos::Rank<3>> (
            {0, 0, 0},
            {numLines[0], numLines[1], numLines[2]},
            {dimTiles[0], dimTiles[1], dimTiles[2]}
        ),
        [=](
            const uint32_t i,
            const uint32_t j,
            const uint32_t k
        ) {
            for (uint32_t n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                volt(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                curr(i, j, k, n) = 0;

                vv(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                vi(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                iv(i, j, k, n) = 0;
                ii(i, j, k, n) = 0;
            }
        }
    );
    Kokkos::fence();

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock().now();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < timesteps; i++) {
        Kokkos::parallel_for("UpdateVoltages",
            Kokkos::MDRangePolicy<Kokkos::Rank<3>> (
                {0, 0, 0},
                {numLines[0], numLines[1], numLines[2]},
                {dimTiles[0], dimTiles[1], dimTiles[2]}
            ),
            [=](
                const uint32_t i,
                const uint32_t j,
                const uint32_t k
            ) {
                UpdateVoltagesKernel(volt, curr, vv, vi, i, j, k);
            }
        );

        Kokkos::fence();
    }

    Kokkos::fence();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock().now();
    double dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() / 1e6;

    size_t bytes_per_iteration = numLines[0] * numLines[1] * numLines[2] * 3 * sizeof(float);
    bytes_per_iteration *= 5;  /* volt r+w, curr, vv, vi arrays */
    fprintf(stderr, "traffic: %.1f GB/s\n", (double) bytes_per_iteration * timesteps / 1000 / 1000 / 1000);
    fprintf(stderr, "speed: %.1f GB/s\n",
        (double) bytes_per_iteration * timesteps / dt / 1000 / 1000 / 1000
    );

    Kokkos::finalize();
}
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(fdtd-kokkos CXX)

set(KOKKOS_IN_TREE "/home/fdtd/kokkos")
add_subdirectory(${KOKKOS_IN_TREE} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/kokkos)

file (GLOB project_SOURCE ${project_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
foreach (sourcefile ${project_SOURCE})
    get_filename_component(sourcename ${sourcefile} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${sourcename} ${sourcefile})
    target_link_libraries(
        ${sourcename} Kokkos::kokkoscore Kokkos::kokkossimd

    )
    target_include_directories(
        ${sourcename} PUBLIC ${project_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
endforeach (sourcefile ${project_SOURCE_DIR})
```

To replicate the build, save source code to `project/src/`, save `CMakeLists.txt` to `project/CMakeLists.txt`, save a copy of Kokkos (from https://github.com/kokkos/kokkos.git) to `/home/fdtd/kokkos`. Then:

```
export CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native"
export CXXFLAGS="-O3 -march=native"
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ../ -DKokkos_ENABLE_THREADS=ON -DKokkos_ENABLE_HWLOC=ON
```

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is to allow GCC to deduce the fact that the member variable `m_grid` held by each `ArrayIJKN` (including `volt`, `curr`, `vv`, and `vi`) point to the same instance of `Grid`.

So far I'm unable to find a satisfactory solution, but the following are partial solutions.

### `abort()` or `return` if assumptions are violated

One partial solution that enables better code generation of GCC is changing the definition of `ASSUME`. Instead of calling `__builtin_unreachable();` when the assumptions are broken, we also `abort()` or `return;` from the kernel function first:

```
#define ASSUME(cond)                    \
    do {                                \
        if (!(cond)) {                  \
            abort();                    \
            __builtin_unreachable();    \
        }                               \
    } while (0)
```

This change allows the implicit compute kernel to reach a speed of 80 GB/s, as fast as the non-inlined version of the explicit version.

Unfortunately, although 90 GB/s is possible, both solutions cannot reach the full 110 GB/s with or without forced inlining in GCC 12. Meanwhile, in GCC 13, this workaround allows GCC's `assume` to work as well as clang, and is able to reach 110 GB/s.

### Templating `grid`

The best but unsatisfactory workaround I've found so far is change `grid` from a runtime parameter of `ArrayIJKN` to a template parameter which can be determined at compile-time.

So instead of:

```
template <typename T, uint32_t n_num=3>
struct ArrayIJKN
{
        ArrayIJKN(
                const std::string& name,
                const Grid& grid
        ) :
```

I use:

```
template <typename T, Grid& grid, uint32_t n_num=3>
struct ArrayIJKN
{
        ArrayIJKN(
                const std::string& name
        )
```

Then the object `Grid` is redefined as a global variable:

```
std::array<uint32_t, 3> numLines = {
        200, 200, 200
};
std::array<uint32_t, 3> dimTiles = {
        20, 20, 20
};

auto grid = Grid(numLines, dimTiles);

// ...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        Kokkos::initialize(argc, argv);

        auto volt = ArrayIJKN<float, grid>("volt");
        auto curr = ArrayIJKN<float, grid>("curr");

        auto vv = ArrayIJKN<float, grid>("vv");
        auto vi = ArrayIJKN<float, grid>("vi");
        auto ii = ArrayIJKN<float, grid>("ii");
        auto iv = ArrayIJKN<float, grid>("iv");
}
```

Then the kernel function is redefined as:

```
void UpdateVoltagesKernel(
        const ArrayIJKN<float, grid>& __restrict__ volt,
        const ArrayIJKN<float, grid>& __restrict__ curr,
        const ArrayIJKN<float, grid>& __restrict__ vv,
        const ArrayIJKN<float, grid>& __restrict__ vi,
        uint32_t i, uint32_t j, uint32_t k
)
```

In this version, GCC's object code has recovered to a speed of 80 GB/s, but was unable to reach the full speed of 100 GB/s. It seems that the forced inlining in array wrapper functions are counter-productive in this case. After removing `__attribute__((always_inline, pure))` from all member functions while still keeping `always_inline` for the kernel function, now GCC is able to generate the high-performance object code that runs at 110+ GB/s without problem, on par with LLVM or the explicit version.

But this workaround is far from satisfactory - the variable Grid must be defined globally and it must appear before defining any other functions. More suggestions are welcomed.